# Custom UILocalNotification repeat interval

Tags: iphone, notifications, local, uilocalnotification

is there a way to specify which days should an UILocalNotification fire? I want to be able to set different days, lets say: fire a local notification only on mondays, tuesdays and sundays. Is there a way to do that? Huge thanks!
Update: Maybe I can set multiple local notifications for each of the days and give each of them a repeatInterval of NSWeekCaldnerUnit. Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use three different local notification then.

For a list of available repeatIntervals see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit).

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do it manually by using this method.. dateByAddingTimeInterval().Just enter some time like 24*60*60 to that method which is fired after a day.Try it with some cases you want.

Comment: are you creating date and pass it to "dateComponents " or what ?

Comment: Yes exactly.  24*60*60 this is the duration of the time when the notification should be fired. I have mentioned above format for 24 hours from currect time.